# understanding bootstrap.js variable declaration

Tags: javascript

I was just looking at the code in bootstrap modal.js and I have the following difficulty:

```
bootstrap Modal.js code : 

  var Modal = function (element, options) {
    this.options             = options
    this.$body               = $(document.body)
    this.$element            = $(element)
    this.$dialog             = this.$element.find('.modal-dialog')
    this.$backdrop           = null
    this.isShown             = null
    this.originalBodyPad     = null
    this.scrollbarWidth      = 0
    this.ignoreBackdropClick = false

 }
```

In my code i did the following:

```
  var Modal = function(element , options){
    this.options = options
    this.$body = $(document.body)
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.isShown = null
    this.scrollbarWidth = 0
    this.$backdrop = 
  }
```

An error was thrown (see the last variable) so I changed my code to as follows:

```
  var Modal = function(element , options){
    this.options = options
    this.$body = $(document.body)
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.isShown = null
    this.$backdrop = 
    this.scrollbarWidth = 0
  }
```

And everything worked fine, why did the error occur? I get a SyntaxError in the console.

My section problem: See how `this.$body` is defined in the plugin, it's defined as follows:

```
    this.$body = $(document.body)
```

Now if I try doing `this.$body = $(body)` an error is thrown. Why?

Comment: your `$backdrop` isn't being assigned to anything! theres no right hand side to the `=`

Comment: that isn't valid javascript.

Comment: an earlier version of bootstrap modal.js , had tat same declaration .

Comment: @downvoters ... go check it out https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L16 , they seem to have changed the code now , but if you know how to see previous code of a repo , go check history .

Comment: it has a value - `null`.

Comment: *"IT'S ABSOLUTLY INTENTIONAL"*, well, it's ABSOLUTELY WRONG. You cannot do that. You can't write `x = ;`. That's syntactically invalid.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you go back to whatever version looked like that, it was part of a series of assignments, the last of which set a variable equal to `null`. There is a lot of history on the file. Can you give us a date range when it looked like that?

Comment: @AustinMullins, no i can't , sorry , i donwloaded the file like like 2 months ago , and it was part of the bootstrap 3.2 , i have the files locally , but i guess its not enuf proof .

Comment: [Found it](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/16479e9051614696df3d21acd9d482018da17045/js/modal.js). As has been pointed out in answers, this is a chained assignment.

Comment: `this.$body = $('body')` with quotes around `body`. See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your code you don't have `;` line terminations. This is valid althought not reccomended.

Said that, this:

var Modal = function(element , options){
    this.options = options
    this.$body = $(document.body)
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.isShown = null
    this.scrollbarWidth = 0
    this.$backdrop = 
  }

is **not** valid javascript because you're nor assigning anything to `this.$backdrop`

While this:

```
var Modal = function(element , options){
    this.options = options
    this.$body = $(document.body)
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.isShown = null
    this.$backdrop = 
    this.scrollbarWidth = 0
  }
```

**is valid** because the js interpreter parses the last lines as

`this.$backdrop = this.scrollbarWidth = 0`

that's valid.

It's a common best practice to always use `;` line terminations to avoid errors and misunderstandings like that.

---

**2ND PROBLEM**

`body` is an undefined variable, so `$(body)` throws an error.

`body` is a propery of `document` that is a variable in the global scope.

so as you reference `document.body` you don't get errors.

Alternatively you can access the page body with jquery using

`$('body')`

Comment: document in the global scope , yeah ! that makes perfect sense ! thank you .

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete statement:

```
this.$backdrop =
```

It's a syntax error. You cannot just leave a dangling `=` there, with nothing on the the right side of the assignment.

The reason your second example works:

```
this.$backdrop = 
this.scrollbarWidth = 0
```

Is because that's no longer a dangling `=`. Now, you've written this:

```
this.$backdrop = this.scrollbarWidth = 0
```

which is perfectly valid. `a = b = 0` is the same as `b = 0; a = 0;`.

JavaScript uses semicolons to separate statements, not newlines. However, when you omit semicolons, automatic-semicolon insertion (ASI) takes over, and puts semicolons where they need to go to delimit statements.

The rules for where semicolons are inserted are actually very straight forward, and JavaScript will never add one when it would introduce a syntax error (specifically, JavaScript will look at whether a line ends in a binary operator and whether the following line is a valid operand). So, your working example, the two lines are parsed as a single expression.

In the case of your broken example, there is no way to insert a semicolon to save this:

```
    // ...
    this.$backdrop = 
}
```

With or without a semicolon, that will be a syntax error.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/16479e9051614696df3d21acd9d482018da17045/js/modal.js

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik So what? I've explained this in my answer